# How to use SSH connect Gitea and SourceTree?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, gitea

now I long to build a private git server myself by gitea and use SourceTree as a git GUI (on Windows)

Current situation & steps:

1.I've already set up a host with gitea, and create a repos here.

2.I used SourceTree (putty) to create a public SSH key and save the .ppk file.

3.Adding this SSH on gitea page (something might be wrong because there is a verification button)
[image: SSH on gitea]

4.Using Pageant.exe on client to add key

[image]

5.Using SourceTree and try to clone the new repos by SSH
[image: SSH url]

6.However, SourceTree on Client can not recognize the url

[image]

note:

1.both two computers connect to Local Area Network

2.opening port:3000 on host is done, and using "telnet HOSTNAME 3000" on client is successful

3.error message when using git command is here
[image: error]

Is there any step I did wrong?

Comment: You're obviously not running any SSHd at `localhost:22`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Could you provide more details? I am a beginner in git and related settings

Comment: The URL possibly should start with `ssh://` - but on Windows, there's no OpenSSH server... so you could only use `http://` or a local file-system path. Setting up a SSH server on Linux would make life easier (or use a Hyper-V container). Also, serving from the user profile `~` is generally not recommend, with SE Linux even prevented by default.